# How can I make custom Swing Containers?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans making an application in Swing. I've created a expandable/foldable drawer to be used in various situations that is meant to contain other GUI components.

This is similar to that of things like JPanel, JScrollPane, JTabbedPane, etc.

However, when I drag my component in to the designer, I cannot add any components under it. Is there a way to make my drawer a container?

Additional Info:
I have selected an example jPanel for instance, note how it has the '+' option. You can add child components under it. My own components, SideDrawer and ScrollableLoadableStripedTables have no such option. I'd like to be able to add it. I'd like to make my component, which extends JPanel act more like a container

[image: Display]
[image: SwingContainers]

Comment: Yes. For more help post [mre]

Comment: I've added some additional information to help